# How to get Github Pages repo URL if you only know the CNAME

Tags: github, github-api, github-pages

Let's say you're visiting a webpage that's hosted on github pages. Maybe it's `www.someProject.com`. How would you get either:

- the github URL (something like `github.com/someUser/someProject`)
- OR the pages url without the CNAME (which would be something like `someUser.github.io/someProject`)?

Can you use GitHub's API for this? I'd like to be able to do this programmatically from the web browser.

Comment: This is not possible with Github API. It doesn't play with custom domains.